# How do we draw the trigonometric function when the y variable is a fraction?

Tags: trigonometry

How do we draw the trigonometric function when the y variable is a fraction?

For example:

$\frac1y=4\cos (\pi x)$

As I am able to draw normal graphs when the $y$ variable is just $y$, but am unsure of how to do this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You could solve for $y$ first.

Comment: plot $y=\dfrac{1}{4 \cos (\pi x)}$

Comment: $$y=\frac1{4\cos(\pi x)}=\frac14\sec(\pi x)$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the equation to become $y= \frac14 cos (\pi x)$ 
And then graphed it. so that the amplitude became $ \frac14 $ meaning it was close to the x-axis. Hence a more squished looking graph.

Thank you for your help.

edit:

I see.

As per the second provided above comment would that mean that it is an asymptotic curve?

That is it cannot be less than $y=\frac 14$ or greater than $y=\frac {-1}{4}$

Comment: That's not quite right. That's the plot for $16y = 4\cos(\pi x)$.